# angularjs ng-repeat filter multiple fields in select options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, multi-select, angularjs-filter

I have problem while filtering based on options in select and then filter in ng-repeat with multiple fields. If i select English Language i have to get English movies and if i select English , Hindi i have to get both English and Hindi Movies together.

Here is my code

```
    <div class="container languageSelect pull-right col-xs-12" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="moviesCtrl">
         <select id="selectTitle" ng-options="option for option in languageslist" ng-model="selectedLang.movielanguage" multiple="multiple"></select>
    </div>

    <div class="">
        <figure class="movie" ng-repeat="record in movieslist | filter: selectedLang">
             <a href="#!/movieHomePage" ng-click="showDetails(record)"><img height="300" width="192" class="poster" ng-src='{{record.imageurl}}' alt="{{record.moviename}} Image">
             <figcaption class="moviename">{{record.moviename}}</figcaption></a>
        </figure>
    </div>
```

Here is my .Js file

```
       app.controller('moviesCtrl',['$scope', function($scope) {

$scope.selectedLang = { movielanguage:"" };
$scope.recordDetails= undefined;
$scope.languageslist = ["English", "Hindi","Kannada","Malayalam","Tamil", "Telugu"];
$scope.movieslist= [
    {"movieId": "0001", "moviename" : "Aval", "imageurl" : "", "movielanguage":"Tamil" },
    {"movieId": "0002", "moviename" : "Blade Runner", "imageurl" : "", "movielanguage":"English" },
    {"movieId": "0003", "moviename" : "Geostorm", "imageurl" : "", "movielanguage":"English" },
    {"movieId": "0004", "moviename" : "Golmaal Again", "imageurl" : "", "movielanguage":"Hindi" },
    {"movieId": "0005", "moviename" : "ITTEFAQ", "imageurl" : "", "movielanguage":"Hindi" },
    {"movieId": "0006", "moviename" : "Mersal", "imageurl" : "", "movielanguage":"tamil" },
    {"movieId": "0011", "moviename" : "PSV Garuda Vega", "imageurl" : "", "movielanguage":"telugu" },
    {"movieId": "0011", "moviename" : "Raja The Great", "imageurl" : "", "movielanguage":"telugu" },
    {"movieId": "0007", "moviename" : "Secret Superstar", "imageurl" : "", "movielanguage":"hindi" },
    {"movieId": "0008", "moviename" : "Solo", "imageurl" : "", "movielanguage":"malayalam" },
    {"movieId": "0009", "moviename" : "The Foreigner", "imageurl" : "", "movielanguage":"english" },
    {"movieId": "0010", "moviename" : "Thor Ragnarok", "imageurl" : "", "movielanguage":"english" },
    {"movieId": "0011", "moviename" : "Villain", "imageurl" : "", "movielanguage":"malayalam" }
]

$scope.showDetails = function (record) {
  $scope.model.recordDetails = record;
};

$(function () {
    $('#selectTitle').multiselect({
        width: 200,
        nonSelectedText: 'Select Language',
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        nSelectedText: 'Languages Selected',
    });
});    
}]);
```

Comment: Can you share me with $scope.selectedLang json value

Comment: i haven't given any values as to it. Initiated with Empty array

Comment: Naga, if you don't mind a suggestion: As your english is not native (and so are many others SO users, including me), you can improve expected answers by including in the question a example of your expected result in the HTML.

Comment: Where you are struggling now.whether multiple drop-down selection or filter

Comment: If i don't use multiple attribute in select tag, I can filter for single option. But when i insert multiple attribute i am having issues

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid ng-repeat in the drop-down selection list. You will use it ng-option that is will be a better one.

```
record in movieslist | filter: {movielanguage: "Tamil"}

Your code
record in movieslist | filter: {movielanguage: selectedLang.movielanguage}


<div class="">
        <figure class="movie" ng-repeat="record in movieslist | filter: {movielanguage: selectedLang}">
             <a href="#!/movieHomePage" ng-click="showDetails(record)"><img height="300" width="192" class="poster" ng-src='{{record.imageurl}}' alt="{{record.moviename}} Image">
             <figcaption class="moviename">{{record.moviename}}</figcaption></a>
        </figure>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm using ng-options only. If i don't use multiple attribute in select tag, I can filter for single option. But when i insert multiple attribute i am having issues

Comment: record in movieslist | filter: {movielanguage: "Tamil"} but i want multiple selection like Tamil, English and Hindi when checked

Comment: Ok. You can write a custom filter logic otherwise not yet to get the value.